# Работа с текстовыми полями Edit1.Text из своих процедур в Lazarus

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Хочу сделать функцию очистки текстовых полей, т.к. одно и то же действие предполагается делать при помощи двух кнопок (кнопкой очистить и после сохранения текстового файла) - то это уменьшит размер кода.
Для этого делаю процедуру:

```
procedure Edit_Clear();
begin
  Edit1.Text:='';
end;
```

И вызываю ее после нажатия кнопки:

```
procedure TForm1.Clear_BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit_Clear()
end;
```

Но Lazarus при компиляции говорит что переменная Edit1 не найдена `(unit1.pas(190,3) Error: Identifier not found "Edit1" )`. При этом если работать с ней в стандартной функции, которую генерирует Lazarus - она выполняется.
Как сделать свою функцию, которая могла бы работать с текстовым полем?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте метод формы - объявите Edit_Clear() в public разделе формы, и сгенерируйте имплементацию (в Delphi это делается CTRL-SHIFT-C, если у вас нет такого шортката, то другой должен быть или просто руками)

```
procedure TForm1.Edit_Clear();
```

Внутри метода будут видны поля формы.

Иначе, если вы хотите иметь standalone процедуру (не метод)  (хотя в данном случае смысла в этом нет), вам придётся обращаться к полям формы через `Form1.Edit1`  (Form1 обычно объявлено в var разделе, но может быть и удалено оттуда программистом)

Comment: Дополнение: всё это потому, что `Edit1` — это не переменная, а поле в классе `TForm1`. Доступ к нему можно получить либо из метода класса, либо через переменную экземпляр класса (по умолчанию глобальная `Form1`), но использование глобальных переменных не рекомендуется, потому что может привести к неожиданным проблемам в будущем.

Answer (score 0):

Так может быть или я не понял вопроса?

```
procedure Edit_Clear(var edit0: Tedit);
begin
  Edit0.Text:='';
end;
```

Использовать тогда

```
procedure TForm1.Clear_BtnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit_Clear(edit1);
end;
```